# R - Loss labels when I ordered a data frame after using read_sav from haven package

Tags: r, r-haven

I use the `read_sav` function from `haven` package to import an SPSS file. Therefore I have column names and associate labels (class `labelled`).

I lost the labels when I ordered the data frame. I can avoid the problem with a conversion in factor before order but is it a bug or a normal behavior ?

Here is a simple example.

`DataForExample <- structure(list(CollectorNm = structure(c("Email Invitation 8", 
"Email Invitation 8", "Email Invitation 8", "Email Invitation 8", 
"Email Invitation 8", "Email Invitation 8"), label = "CollectorNm"), 
    q0001 = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), label = "Avez-vous déjà suivi la formation Atlas-Vente des 18 et 19 octobre ?", class = "labelled", labels = structure(c(1, 
    2), .Names = c("Oui, j'ai bien suivi cette formation.", "Non, je n'y ai pas participé."
    ))), q0002_0001 = structure(c(3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3), label = "La formation dans son ensemble", class = "labelled", labels = structure(c(1, 
    2, 3, 4), .Names = c("pas du tout satisfait", "plutôt pas satisfait", 
    "plutôt satisfait", "très satisfait")))), .Names = c("CollectorNm", 
"q0001", "q0002_0001"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L))`

`View(DataForExample) # OK
Toto <- DataForExample[order(DataForExample$q0001_0001),]
View(Toto) # NOK : the labels disappeared`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load package with support for subsetting operations for class `labelled`. It is better to load it after the `haven`. There are at least two packages with such support: `Hmisc` and `expss`. Disclaimer: I am an author of the expss package.

**UPDATE.** Fix labelled class.

It seems that `haven` doesn't set `labelled` class for all variables with labels. So we need to fix it:

```
library(expss)

for(each in colnames(DataForExample)){
    if(!("labelled" %in% class(DataForExample[[each]])) && 
       (!is.null(var_lab(DataForExample[[each]])) ||
        !is.null(val_lab(DataForExample[[each]]))
       )) {
        class(DataForExample[[each]]) = union("labelled", class(DataForExample[[each]]))
    }
}

View(DataForExample) # OK
Toto <- DataForExample[order(DataForExample$q0001),]
View(Toto) # OK
```

Comment: Thanks. It's OK for the example that I made but the problem remains for a more complex data frame.  I precise that I try with the two packages. It seems that the problem arise when there is (future) factor variables and (future) string variables, so I changed the example in my question.